# RNN Keras Error || No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by {{node CudnnRNN}} with these attrs

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, cudnn

I am currently working on a RNN using Keras, but I am stuck with this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 32
     28 parameters = {"batch_size": [32],
     29               "epochs": [100],
     30               "optimizer": ["adam"]}
     31 grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor, param_grid=parameters, n_jobs=-1)
---> 32 grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
     34 best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
     35 best_precision = grid_search.best_score_

File c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:874, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    868     results = self._format_results(
    869         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    870     )
    872     return results
--> 874 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    876 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
    877 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
    878 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:1388, in GridSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1386 def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1387     """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1388     evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

File c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:851, in BaseSearchCV.fit..evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    844 elif len(out) != n_candidates * n_splits:
    845     raise ValueError(
    846         "cv.split and cv.get_n_splits returned "
    847         "inconsistent results. Expected {} "
    848         "splits, got {}".format(n_splits, len(out) // n_candidates)
    849     )
--> 851 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(out, self.error_score)
    853 # For callable self.scoring, the return type is only know after
    854 # calling. If the return type is a dictionary, the error scores
    855 # can now be inserted with the correct key. The type checking
    856 # of out will be done in `_insert_error_scores`.
    857 if callable(self.scoring):

File c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:367, in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    360 if num_failed_fits == num_fits:
    361     all_fits_failed_message = (
    362         f"\nAll the {num_fits} fits failed.\n"
    363         "It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.\n"
    364         "You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.\n\n"
    365         f"Below are more details about the failures:\n{fit_errors_summary}"
    366     )
--> 367     raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)
    369 else:
    370     some_fits_failed_message = (
    371         f"\n{num_failed_fits} fits failed out of a total of {num_fits}.\n"
    372         "The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters"
   (...)
    376         f"Below are more details about the failures:\n{fit_errors_summary}"
    377     )

ValueError: 
All the 5 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py", line 175, in fit
    history = self.model.fit(x, y, **fit_args)
  File "c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "c:\Users\rdcle\anaconda3\envs\tfamdgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by {{node CudnnRNN}} with these attrs: [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", seed2=0, is_training=true]
Registered devices: [CPU, GPU]
Registered kernels:
  

     [[CudnnRNN]]
     [[sequential/lstm/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_15618]
```

This is my code:

```
def build_regressor(optimizer):
    regressor = Sequential()

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 5)))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=100))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

    regressor.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error")

    return regressor

regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_regressor)
parameters = {"batch_size": [8, 16, 32, 64],
              "epochs": [100, 200, 300],
              "optimizer": ["adam", "adadelta", "rmsprop"]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor, param_grid=parameters, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", n_jobs=-1)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train) # <-- There is the error
```

Also, I tried to use a different optimizer, like AdamW, but it just did not solve my problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

*(Note: I am working on a anaconda environment called "tfamdgpu" on DirectML and Tensorflow 2. I have installed it according to this: [microsoft-gpu-tensorflow-plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-plugin))*

Comment: Hi! Would you mind providing some example data so that it is possible to run the code?

Comment: Here I can give the stock price data that I used ([https://mega.nz/someFile/](https://mega.nz/file/1X1EkZhb#Z_aQRujlyIQDaacwvaMxMq59L7hQ5uaoODYzClyEVM4)). Please tell me if you want the complete code with the data preprocessing part.